# Using Swift to store a Photo as blob in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, swift, swift5

I need to use swift to store a number of fields in a MySQL database but for some reason, the photo field does not work. Any Advice? (Error - Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?') Swift connects to PHP which then sends the information to MySQL. Everything works perfectly except for the photo. I can't seem to figure out how to send the to SQL as a BLOB file.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    imageView.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
}

@IBOutlet weak var FirstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Photo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var LastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ID: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var City: UITextField!
@IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
//put the link of the php file here. The php file connects the mysql and swift
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://alpha-rage.co.za/storevalue.php")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let postString = "a=\(FirstName.text!)&b=\(LastName.text!)&c=\(ID.text!)&d=\(City.text!)&e=\(Photo.image!)"

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
}
task.resume()

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Candidate's Name", message:
    "Successfully Added", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,handler: nil))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            FirstName.text = ""
            LastName.text = ""
            ID.text = ""
            City.text = ""
            Photo.image = ""

        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

Comment: Still not winning with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to send the image to a server in JSON, you'll need to do two things.

First convert it to a standard image format (say JPEG)

```
let jpegData = Photo.image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
```

Now you are going to have to convert the data to a format that can be placed in JSON. The best way to this would be convert it to base64.

```
let base64String = jpegData.base64EncodedString()
```

You can insert `base64String` into your JSON. At the server end you can do a base64 decode.

So your code would be as follows

```
// jpegData creation can fail so you need to deal with it. If image is in wrong format or UIImage has no data
guard let jpegData = Photo.image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {return}
let base64String = jpegData.base64EncodedString()
let postString = "a=\(FirstName.text!)&b=\(LastName.text!)&c=\(ID.text!)&d=\(City.text!)&e=\(base64String)"
```

Of course you could skip the base64 encoding and send the JPEG data as raw data without the JSON. The other fields could be sent as URL query parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. How would I amend the code above to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

**STOP!** That's a terrible idea! Store the file somewhere on the server, and store the file's **PATH** in the database.

You'll thank me later ;-)

Comment: I wish i could but one of our existing programs already make use of images in this fashion.  So I have no choice I must develop the mobile app in accordance with the desktop version. May I ask why it's not recommended?

Comment: How would i amend my code to accomplish this should management approve of the idea?

Comment: upon posting the image, `move_uploaded_file()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php to a protected uploads folder, and then store the path in the db. then create an endpoint going to a download controller, so you could have something like `<img src="/download?file=<?= $imgPath ?>" />`, the controller would `file_get_contents()`, `header()` the content type, and echo the contents